# Configuration Manager is looking for policy

Tags: sccm, configuration-management

I've tried all the solutions proposed in the web with no luck.

The computer that i'm trying to boot is **unknown** for the ConfigMgr.

I've created two task sequences (x86 and x64) and applied them to All Unknown Computers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Have you configured the option "Enable unknown computer support" on the DP that is servicing the PXE request?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the unknown computer support is enabled, and if the collection "All Unknown Computers" has the correct TS deployment?

[image]